# Can't Import Rich Python Libary

Tags: python, import, rich

**SOLVED**

I'm trying to import the rich python library into my script, but it isn't working.

I was able to install it with
`pip install rich` but my script doesn't seem to recognize it as being installed.

To make sure it was installed I ran `python -m rich` which displays all of the features rich adds, and that ran correctly as well.

But if we look in my script where it's being imported, there's an error line below rich saying it isn't recognized. Specifically it says that "Import 'rich' could not be resolved"
[screenshot of the import line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8uJL.png)

Has anyone encountered this before?

**SOLUTION**
Had to restart visual studio code and it fixed it

Comment: Make sure you use the same interpreter. Maybe you installed it for one Python version, but using another...